# Fade in on Scroll ( Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, cross-fade

I want to implement this codes
but it doesn't work for me , every things is ok but "Fade in" divs not showing for me. can anyone help me why it doesn't work ?
I try it in MVC5 application , adding scripts in mvc5 is difference with other versions ?!

HTML :

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#container
{
height:2000px;    
}

#container DIV
{ 
margin:50px; 
padding:50px; 
background-color:lightgreen; 
}

.hideme
 {
 opacity:0;
 }
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        }

    }); 

});

});
```

this is Demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qad/)

Comment: It works.(Chrome 46.0.2490.86 m and Firefox 42)

Comment: `$(window).scroll();` Should be out of `$(document).ready();` I think.

Comment: thanks , my chrome is 44 but I saw this effect in other sites , what can I do to work it in all versions and browsers ?!

Comment: I edit it to  $(window).scroll(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () { ..... but it doesn't work still :/ @MajidSadr

Comment: Is javascript of your browser enable?

Comment: yes I think, it's enable

Comment: @shimaamini I mean you should delete `$(document).ready();` From your code.

Comment: shima jan un function ke baraye `$(window).scroll();` neveshti ro bayad az `$(document).ready();` joda koni . kolan `$(document).ready();` ro az codet hazf kon.

Comment: ahan , kheyli mamnoon man bad motevaje shodam . alan testesh mikonam omidvaram doros she , kheyli mamnoon  @MajidSadr

Comment: Doros nashod motasefane :/ albate pashimoon shodam az in script estefade nemikonam chon yekam search kardam engar goftan karaii site ro pain miare , be har hal mamnoon :)  @MajidSadr

Comment: @shimaamini etefaghan kare badi ham nist jaleb mishe . alan as fiddle man emtehan kardam dorost kar mikard . ye check bekonid ke JQuery ro daroon rizi kardin ya na . moafagh bashid :)